# Why is my Fluent 2's Combobox not working?

Tags: fluent-ui

I'm having issues with Fluent's combo box that is blowing up the call stack with some kind of recursion issue (looks like it is calling getComputedStyle) whenever it gets clicked on or focused via keyboard.

While I started with something fairly complex, I've dumbed it down to (nearly) the simplest possible usable case.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Default as ComboboxProxy} from './Components/ComboboxProxy';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ComboboxProxy />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

This was literally the code from the Fluent sample (https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-combobox--default), although I've further simplified the case by removing some styling:

```
export const Default = (props: Partial<ComboboxProps>) => {
  const comboId = useId("combo-default");
  const options = ["Cat", "Dog", "Ferret", "Fish", "Hamster", "Snake"];
  return (
    <div>
      <label id={comboId}>Best pet</label>
      <Combobox
        aria-labelledby={comboId}
        placeholder="Select an animal"
        {...props}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option} disabled={option === "Ferret"}>
            {option}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Combobox>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thoughts/suggestions?  I have StrictMode set here because it is in the Microsoft sample, but have tried it without, or inside of a FluentProvider as well.  Behavior is the same even across several different methods of trying to instantiate.